# Вызов внешей программы в С++

Tags: windows, c++

Необходимо вызвать внешнюю программу для дальнейшей работы с ней.

Answer (score 2):

Самое простое:

```
 UINT WinExec(

        LPCSTR lpCmdLine,   // address of command line 
        UINT uCmdShow   // window style for new application 
       );
```

Но "правильнее" CreateProcess 
PS Чисто виндовозовские функции

Comment: а где указывать наименование вызываемой программы?

Comment: в lpCmdLine путь к программе (или название, если лежит в рабочей директории)
второй параметр может быть SW_SHOW, SW_HIDE и ряд других (см. ShowWindow)
Да! Еще есть ShellExecute! Ею можно выполнить bat файлы, а также файлы с зарегистрированными расширениями

Comment: большое спасибо, пойду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
system(const char *command) -- выполнить внешнюю команду, есть ещё масса вариантов, но зависит от системы -- нужен Вам стандартный вызов POSIX.1 или виндовый, и как Вы собираетесь с ней работать.
```

Comment: мне нужен виндовый, и чтоб программа потом уже работать непосредственной с данной программой

Comment: "программа потом уже работать непосредственной с данной программой" -- это что значит. Что обе программы работают и взаимодействуют между собой. Или вторая программа работает вместо первой? Или каждая сама по себе?

Comment: в общем первая программа по сути дела является набором средств, то есть программ. исходя из определенных требований и условий будет необходимость вызова одной из имеющихся программ, для дальнейшей работы с ней. то есть каждая программа получается будет работать сама по себе. первая программа должна служит лишь для вызова одной из имеющихся в ее списке.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX-функции для вызова процессов объявлены в process.h. Это функции серий exec и spawn

Comment: @P5, автор вопроса, написал, что ему нужна виндовая

Comment: ну и что, работать будет